# How to read a random folder structure with Javascript living at the same level as index.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a testing reporting tool that generates a list of images grouped by folders, so you could end up with a structure like this:

`root/
  /counter/
    img1.png
    img2.png
  /alarm/
    img3.png`

where `counter` and `alarm` are not fixed names: these are given by the user in a previous step, so they might change all the time.

What I want to do is to add a `index.html` inside `root` that can list all the folders and images inside those folders with javascript, but I can't seem to find the right JS API to do this. I have no problems generating the `index.html` report, but I don't know what should be the exact JS script to read that folder structure that is not fixed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What language are you using to generate the index.html file? How are you generating it?

You can't list files on a server with plain front-end (browser run) javascript. You need a server side language to list the files on a server, like [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) or [php](https://php.net), they can send a list of files/folders in JSON or something similar that you can parse with JS.

Checkout [scandir for php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) and [fs.readDir for nodejs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback)

Answer (score 0):

I was using Dart to generate these reports. I ended up reading the folder with Dart code and autogenerating the HTML content rather than using JS for this task.
Thanks!